# How to connect via afp?

Tags: macosx

I want to get files from Apple machine on my ubuntu (installed in virtual box)
is there any process to do that?

normally, I want to do:

```
afp://myapplecomputer
```

if I try to open with file browser(on Location), it says

> nautilus cannot handle "afp" locations

Answer (score 4):

I simply did

```
apt-get install afpfs-ng
```

Then I was able to mount AFP shares via the CLI as

```
mount_afp afp://user:password@192.168.1.101/sharename /media/AFP
```

Works beautifully!

Comment: Package does not work on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @jjxtra To be more precise, the package is not present [in the default repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=afp&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) for Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 3):

OS X responds to both AFP and SMB by default.  If you can't use SMB for some reason, `sudo apt-get install netatalk`.  It doesn't look like netatalk has any bindings for either Gnome-VFS or Nautilus, though, so you'll have to work from a command line.

Comment: ahh, thanks for response, what command lines are there to get ? you are saying to type on terminal ?

Comment: Yes, unless you can find Nautilus integration for AFP (the best I've found is http://www.kremalicious.com/2008/06/ubuntu-as-mac-file-server-and-time-machine-volume/ which also notes the lack of Nautilus integration).

Comment: +1 - Installing `netatalk` is the way to go here. As an added bonus, you can enter into a terminal `$ sudo apt-get install avahi-daemon`. "Avahi allows programs to publish and discover services and hosts running on a local network with no specific configuration." This is known as Bonjour in OS X. `avahi-daemon` allows your AFP shares to show up as Bonjour shares in OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Install [afpfs-ng](http://sourceforge.net/projects/afpfs-ng/), I installed version 0.8.1 from source using the following directions (I found some old instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.org/wiki/Mount_an_AFP_share_from_Linux), but there is a typo so I have adjusted it to match the INSTALL instruction that came with the source files.)

Install the dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install lbgcrypt-dev libgmap-dev readline-dev libfuse-dev
```

Unzip the tar.bz2 file, cd into the resulting folder, build and install

```
tar -xfz afpfs-ng-0.8.1.tar.bz2
cd afpfs-ng-0.8.1
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

It appears that they actually have a .deb file too, [see here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/afpfs-ng/files/afpfs-ng/0.8.1/), but I didn't notice it until I started typing this response.

After installing you can then mount an afp share from the command line, its not quite as nice as just putting `afp://share` into nautilus, but certainly better than nothing.  Mount using

```
afp_client mount -u <user_name> -p <password> <server>:<volume> <mountpoint>
```

where `<mountpoint>` is a folder that the current user has read and write permissions.  If you use `-` for `password` you will be asked for the password interactively, like when you use `sudo`. I highly recommend this, otherwise your password will be displayed on your screen in plain text.  After all of that, the mount should appear in your nautilus side bar.

When you are done and wish to unmount the share, you can not use the eject button that is displayed in nautilus.  Instead use the following command

```
afp_client unmount <mountpoint>
```

If you like using the command line, then there is also the command `afpcmd` that behaves like a command line ftp client.

Answer (score 0):

It should work in nautilius as the fisrt user asked for, 
connect : 
afp://user@ip

I did install 
sudo apt-get install afpfs-ng

but don't think one needs to do it , ubuntu 13.04