# How do I share files with a Mac?

Tags: 11.04, file-sharing

I would like to allow a Mac user on the same network to edit (in-place) a stylesheet file on my localhost.

Hence I would like to share `/var/www/site1` with users on the network.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could install gshare.

with it you can select what folders you want to share just by right clicking them.

```
sudo apt-get install gshare
```

Here is my home folder that I share in my local network.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

NFS is also an option. Read the [Ubuntu NFS documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/network-file-system.html) for instructions on how to set up the NFS server. See this [Apple KB document](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA22243) for easy instruction on how to connect to the NFS server.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Mac supports samba (SMB) so you could set up a share that way.  There are instructions for setting up a samba share on the [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/samba-fileserver.html) site.

The other possibility is [netatalk](http://netatalk.sourceforge.net/).  This allows you to set up a share in the mac native AFP protocal.  I found some decent instructions for setting this up on the [missingreadme blog](http://missingreadme.wordpress.com/2010/05/08/how-to-set-up-afp-filesharing-on-ubuntu/).

I should note that I don't believe that netatalk will allow sharing from your friends mac.  So if you need to get something that they have shared you will want to see this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31626/how-to-connect-via-aftp/).

Answer (score -1):

Use dropbox and create a symbolic link to the folder.

```
ln -s ~/Dropbox/site1 /var/www/site1
```

Comment: dropbox works only with small files or it takes ages to share a file. Once I copied a movie from one of my computers to the other it took 6 hours to copy 600mb. If I do it via the network it takes like 2 minutes.