# Wifi Ubuntu Mac

Tags: wireless, mac

I have a Ubuntu PC and I want to send data to a Mac via Wifi. The best solution would be to have a sharing directory regardless from the Wifi I'm connected to. I didn't find any solution for the moment, can someone help me?

Thank for all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I share files with a Mac?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/43318/how-do-i-share-files-with-a-mac)

Comment: @user3629688: As your question is not marked as solved - can we offer further help? Where are you stuck right now?

Answer (score 4):

*I am assuming you are located in the same local network with both hosts*

There are several ways to do that.

## 1. SSH & SCP

As both systems do know ssh & scp you could easily transfer files via scp.

As far as i know you have to enable SSH/SCP on the Mac via:

**System Preferences** → **Sharing** → select **Remote Login** checkbox.

Usage examples:

```
scp /path/to/local/file remoteusername@remotehost:
```

or for an entire folder

```
scp -r /path/to/local/folder remoteusername@remotehost:
```

in case you want to define the target position as well:

```
scp -r /path/to/local/folder remoteusername@remotehost:/path/on/targetsystem
```

Some additional help for `scp` can be found [here](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php).

## 2. Shared Mac Folder

You could enable a Folder sharing in **System Preferences** → **Sharing** of the Mac.

[image]

Macs usually share via *AFP* and optional *SMB/CIFS*.
You could then mount that share on the ubuntu side in Nautilus (or other File Manager) or permanently via `/etc/fstab`.

## 3. Syncing folders

Setup [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/)/[Owncloud](https://owncloud.org/) or similar on both hosts and enjoy syncing files with all pro and cons.

You could as well use [rsync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) to sync a folder between those 2 machines.

Comment: I would go with SCP

Answer (score 1):

A lazy FLOSS alternative to Dropbox/[Owncloud](https://owncloud.org/) (it is much easier to setup than owncloud) is [syncthing](https://www.syncthing.net/). I use it to sync android and multiple Linux boxes (Ubuntu, openSUSE and Raspbian), but it also works on MacOS.

Just always be sure to use the same version on all clients as the protocol changes over main versions.

Of course using SSH & SCP or SFTP is probably closer to the question you asked.